# Composition of fields and completion?

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $L/K$, $L'/K$ are finite extensions of a number field, $LL'$ be the composition field, let $p$ be a prime in $K$, $q, q'$ be primes over $p$ in $L$ and $L'$ respectively, $q''$ be the prime over $p$ in  $LL'$.

> Will we have completions $(LL')_{q''}\simeq L_q{L'}_{q'}$?

Comment: Yes. Embed $L_q$ and $L_q’$ In a common algebraic closure of $K_p.$ Note now that $(LL’)_{q’’}$ is the smallest complete field containing $LL’.$ Thus $(LL’)_{q’’} \subset L_qL’_{q’}$ since the latter field is complete and contains $LL’.$ For the other containment, note that $L_q,L’_{q’}$ are subfields of $(LL’)_{q’’}$ and then proceed by the definition of the compositum of two field extensions.

Comment: @Dedalus Thanks a lot! It's an answer not only comment though.

Comment: I will post it as an answer later today. I am glad it helped.

Comment: You mean $q''$ is a prime of $LL'$ over $q,q'$ (it doesn't have to exist for every $q'$ but for every $q$ there is a $q'$ such that $q''$ exists). For Galois extensions we don't have this problem because the Galois group acts transitively on the primes above $p$. To understand what is happening take $a$ such that $L = \Bbb{Q}(a)$ and $f \in \Bbb{Q}[x]$ its minimal polynomial then $L_{q_j} = \Bbb{Q}_p(a_j)$ for each root $a_j$ of $f \in \Bbb{Q}_p[x]$ (some $q_i,q_j$ can be the same prime). @Dedalus

Comment: @reuns I agree with your comment, I should have been more precise.